# How to make open() replace file contents?

Tags: c++, file

Please this is really important, any ideas are VERY appreciated. I have been stuck on this for days.

**Updates:**

1. I have added some notes to make things clear.
2. You can run the same code here on: https://onlinegdb.com/HyYP3qguu

---

I wrote the following function in C++ which I call 3 times to open a file and writes to it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

bool try_num=0;

void cmd_execute()
{
    bool single_red = true;
    if (try_num==1) single_red=false;
    try_num++; // global variable starts from 0

    int file_fd, redirect_fd1, redirect_fd2;

    file_fd = (single_red) ? open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666) :
    open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666); //open file
    
    if (file_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("smash error: open failed");
        return;
    }
    redirect_fd1 = dup(1); // duplicate standard output
    if (redirect_fd1 < 0)
    {
        perror("smash error: dup failed");
        return;
    }
    redirect_fd2 = dup2(file_fd, 1); // replace standard output with file
    if (redirect_fd2 < 0)
    {
        perror("smash error: dup2 failed");
        return;
    }
    if (close(file_fd) < 0)//close the other file
    {
        perror("smash error: close failed");
        return;
    }
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    /** end **/
    if (dup2(redirect_fd1, 1) < 0)//close file and replace by standard output
    {
        perror("smash error: dup2 failed");
        return;
    }
    if (close(redirect_fd1) < 0)//close the other standard output
    {
        perror("smash error: close failed");
    }
}
```

When I open my file `test.txt` I see:

```
Hello
Hello
```

why is that? in the third call `single_red` is true which means all contents of file should be erased.

O_WRONLY - means open file in write only mode.

O_CREAT - if file doesn't exist then create it.

O_APPEND - append text to end of file.

Comment: `O_APPEND` means that it will start writing at the end of the current contents, so it won't overwrite it.

Comment: Add the `O_TRUNC` flag to truncate the existing contents.

Comment: @Barmar when single_red is true I don't use O_APPEND

Comment: Then it will overwrite, but not remove anything.

Comment: So if the file contains `abc` and then you write `d` you'll get `dbc`

Answer (score 3):

Use `O_TRUNC` if you want to replace the file contents. Otherwise it will overwrite the file, but not remove whatever is already in it. If you write less than the existing length, you'll see the new contents followed by the remainder of the original contents.

```
    int flags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | (single_red ? O_TRUNC : O_APPEND);
    file_fd = (single_red) ? open("test.txt", flags, 0666); //open file
```

Comment: The OP replied in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409950/

Comment: @me_go If this doesn't solve the problem, you need to post a [mcve] proving it.

Comment: The OP's reply is not credible. This solution will work. We can't be expected to chase duplicate posts all over SO. @RemyLebeau